# How can I load sklearn data in Jupyter Python 3?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hey I have a very short question. I need to load data for my machine learning course, but it does not work for me and I have no idea why. Im using Jupyter with Python 3.
My Code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_covtype
forest = fetch_covtype()
```

For my friend it works fine with the same conditions. I already tried to update sklearn with pip install -U scikit-learn, but it did not solve the problem. I hope somebody can help me.

It creates the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/covtype.py in fetch_covtype(data_home, download_if_missing, random_state, shuffle, return_X_y)
    126     try:
--> 127         X, y
    128     except NameError:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X' referenced before assignment

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-fb303a92b6ca> in <module>
----> 1 forest =fetch_covtype()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/covtype.py in fetch_covtype(data_home, download_if_missing, random_state, shuffle, return_X_y)
    127         X, y
    128     except NameError:
--> 129         X, y = _refresh_cache([samples_path, targets_path], 9)
    130         # TODO: Revert to the following two lines in v0.23
    131         # X = joblib.load(samples_path)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py in _refresh_cache(files, compress)
    928     msg = "sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21"
    929     with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warns:
--> 930         data = tuple([joblib.load(f) for f in files])
    931 
    932     refresh_needed = any([str(x.message).startswith(msg) for x in warns])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    928     msg = "sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21"
    929     with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warns:
--> 930         data = tuple([joblib.load(f) for f in files])
    931 
    932     refresh_needed = any([str(x.message).startswith(msg) for x in warns])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    603                     return load_compatibility(fobj)
    604 
--> 605                 obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    606 
    607     return obj

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    527     obj = None
    528     try:
--> 529         obj = unpickler.load()
    530         if unpickler.compat_mode:
    531             warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in load(self)
   1083                     raise EOFError
   1084                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1085                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1086         except _Stop as stopinst:
   1087             return stopinst.value

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in load_build(self)
    353             if isinstance(array_wrapper, NDArrayWrapper):
    354                 self.compat_mode = True
--> 355             self.stack.append(array_wrapper.read(self))
    356 
    357     # Be careful to register our new method.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in read(self, unpickler)
    196             array = self.read_mmap(unpickler)
    197         else:
--> 198             array = self.read_array(unpickler)
    199 
    200         # Manage array subclass case

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in read_array(self, unpickler)
    147                     read_size = int(read_count * self.dtype.itemsize)
    148                     data = _read_bytes(unpickler.file_handle,
--> 149                                        read_size, "array data")
    150                     array[i:i + read_count] = \
    151                         unpickler.np.frombuffer(data, dtype=self.dtype,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle_utils.py in _read_bytes(fp, size, error_template)
    241     if len(data) != size:
    242         msg = "EOF: reading %s, expected %d bytes got %d"
--> 243         raise ValueError(msg % (error_template, size, len(data)))
    244     else:
    245         return data

ValueError: EOF: reading array data, expected 262144 bytes got 209661
```

Comment: Looks like your download is corrupt. Try deleting the `'covertype'` folder from `~/scikit_learn_data` and try the code again

Comment: That worked btw :) ty